# Can someone explain me this behaviour of recycler view?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am learning about recyclerview and was just trying out some example and I came across this...
When I try to use vertical orientation for my list it works out as desired output is something like this:
[image: vertical orientation image]

and if I change it to horizontal then my view is something like this:

[image: shows one item at a time]

my xml is as shown below

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:background="@color/material100Green"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/rv_numbers"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

My mainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int NUM_LIST_ITEMS = 100;

    private GreenAdapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView mNumbersList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        mNumbersList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv_numbers);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,true);
        mNumbersList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        mNumbersList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        mNumbersList.setHasFixedSize(true);

        /*
         * The GreenAdapter is responsible for displaying each item in the list.
         */
        mAdapter = new GreenAdapter(NUM_LIST_ITEMS);

        mNumbersList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
}
```

GreenAdapter is as shown below:

```
public class GreenAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GreenAdapter.NumberViewHolder> {

    private static final String TAG = GreenAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

    private int mNumberItems;

    public GreenAdapter(int numberOfItems) {
        mNumberItems = numberOfItems;
    }

    @Override
    public NumberViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        Context context = viewGroup.getContext();
        int layoutIdForListItem = R.layout.number_list_item;
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        boolean shouldAttachToParentImmediately = false;

        View view = inflater.inflate(layoutIdForListItem, viewGroup, shouldAttachToParentImmediately);
        NumberViewHolder viewHolder = new NumberViewHolder(view);

        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(NumberViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Log.d(TAG, "#" + position);
        holder.bind(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mNumberItems;
    }

    class NumberViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


        TextView listItemNumberView;

        public NumberViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            listItemNumberView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_number);
        }

        /**
         * This method will take an integer as input and
         * use that integer to display the appropriate text within a list item.
         * @param listIndex Position of the item in the list
         */
        void bind(int listIndex) {
            listItemNumberView.setText(String.valueOf(listIndex));
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone explain me the above behavior?
With that if someone can quote the solution for displaying at least 4-5 items while scrolling horizontally would be appreciated :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: in your number_list_item xml set wrap_content to parent layout

Comment: thanks @DivyeshPatel it worked (y)

Answer (score 1):

As Divesh Patel said

> in your number_list_item xml set wrap_content to parent layout